# Retain / Release mistake

Tags: ios, exc-bad-access, retaincount

I am trying to figure out why I am getting `EXC_BAD_ACESS`  by this code. I have no clu. Can anyone help me pls.

```
- (void)loadJsonFile:(NSString*)fileName {
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSData *jsonData = [[[NSString alloc]
                         initWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle]
                                                 pathForResource:fileName ofType:@"json"]
                         encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error]
                        dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    
    jsonDic = [[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error] retain];
   [jsonData release];
}
```

If I am commenting out the "`[jsonData release];`" line, everything functions. But why ? I allocate `jsonData`, fill it with data and pass it to `NSJSONSerialization` for getting the jsonDic. After I have the serialization, I release the `jsonData` and want to use the jsonDic, however some time after the "`[jsonData release];`" I am getting "`EXC_BAD_ACCESS`" Exception.

I have no clu, any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You release `jsonData`, but you never retained it. The static analyzer (Menu `"Product" ➞ "Analyze"`) would have shown you this problem. Also, you're not releasing the `NSString` you're allocating.

Do it like this:

```
- (void)loadJsonFile:(NSString*)fileName {
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSData *jsonData = [[[[[NSString alloc]
                         initWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle]
                                                 pathForResource:fileName ofType:@"json"]
                         encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error] autorelease]
                        dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] retain];

    jsonDic = [[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error] retain];
    [jsonData release];
}
```

You might want to consider using ARC (Automatic Reference Counting). Xcode can convert your project almost completely automatically with Menu `"Edit" ➞ "Refactor" ➞ "Convert to Objective-C ARC…"`. There are only few reasons to keep managing memory manually.

Comment: Thx a lot. I realized now
a) I am creating a string object that I never release
b) I am releasing the Data Object that I did not own.

Comment: What version of XCode are you using? I am using 3.2.5 and I don't see ARC... in any menu...